# GitLab - run job on PR on bitbucket possible?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, bitbucket

I just setup a project on GitLab with an external Bitbucket repository. I added the webhook to Bitbucket and I'm seeing that I'm sending out requests when I push or open a PR etc.

I would like to execute a test job every time a PR is opened to merge a branch into the master branch on Bitbucket. When the merge happened, I want to run another 2 jobs (build + deploy).

So far my gitlab file looks like

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

buildJob:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo 'Building...'
  only:
    - master

testJob:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo 'Testing...'
  only:
    - external_pull_requests

deployJob:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo 'Deploying...'
  only:
   - master
```

The build and deploy jobs are executed as expected when a merge has happened. However, the job that should only run when a PR is opened (or on any new commit on an already opened PR) is not executed. In the Documentation they only talk about GitHub. Is this actually possible with Bitbucket?